# AngularJS Applying model to dynamic form elements

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to bind model data from a controller to a directive template.  The directive template repeats form input types based on a form object from a controller.

The goal is to use this directive in multiple places and bind the appropriate model to the form as opposed to creating a form each time.

I've found examples using transclusion and isolated scopes, however, each of the examples I've come across seem to have the model properties hardcoded.

Here is a jsfiddle that hopefully explains better what I'm trying to achieve.

http://jsfiddle.net/N9rSa/14/

```
app.controller('FormCtrl',function($scope) {
    $scope.form = [
        {label:'First',type:'text',name:'first_name'},
        {label:'Last',type:'text',name:'last_name'}
    ];

    $scope.person = {first_name:'Jimmy',last_name:'Page'};
});

app.directive('formelements',function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope:false,
        template: '<div ng-repeat="elements in form"><input type="text" ng-model="field.name"></div>'
    }
});
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following as template:

```
template: '<div ng-repeat="element in form">' +
    '<input type="text" ng-model="person[element.name]"></div>'
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g5Mzs/

Essentially the `name` field is used to define the index inside the `person` object.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I figured I could use form_model as my object to apply to the form everytime it's needed:

http://jsfiddle.net/N9rSa/